# representation of a matrix norm of the inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be an $n$ by $n$ nonsingular matrix and suppose that a matrix norm $|||\cdot|||$ is induced by the vector norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Show that
>   $$|||A^{-1}||| = \frac1{\min_{\lVert x \rVert=1}\|Ax\|}.$$

As in below picture I've shown one direction. However, I cannot show the converse direction. How can I do this?

My try for $\le$:
Let $x$ such that $\|x\| = 1$ then
$$1 = \|x\| = \|A^{-1}Ax\| \le ||| A^{-1} ||| \| Ax \| \\ 
\Rightarrow \frac1{\|Ax\|} \le ||| A^{-1} ||| \\
\Rightarrow \frac1{\min_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\|} \le ||| A^{-1} |||$$

Comment: Your picture and body don't match up. $\|| A |\|$ or $\|| A^{-1} |\|$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, the picture is correct

Comment: I fixed a few norms for you ($Ax \in \mathbb C^n$ needs to be in the $\|\cdot\|$-norm, not the matrix-norm $|||\cdot|||$) and TeXified your image.

Comment: Appreciate it Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go all the way in one line:
$$||| A^{-1} ||| = \sup_{y\ne 0} \frac{\|A^{-1}y\|}{\|y\|} \stackrel{(\ast)}= \sup_{x\ne 0} \frac{\|x\|}{\|Ax\|} = \sup_{\|x\|=1}\frac1{\|Ax\|} = \frac1{\inf_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\|}$$
In $(\ast)$ we use that $A$ is invertible, so $\{y | y\ne 0\} = \{x | Ax \ne 0\}$ so we maximise over the same set under the substitution $y = Ax$.